# Customized vertical navigation drawer

Tags: android, customization, navigation-drawer, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to find an example of a navigation drawer that opens upwards for ~1/4 of the screen. I'd like to implement this, but it seems like that would be going against it's intended use since the only two gravity options are "start" and "left."

Ultimately, I'd like to implement this vertical opening functionality in a music playlist sort of app, because I think that the "rewind, fast-forward, and pause" buttons take away from the minimal and unintrusive design of the app. Likewise, it just wouldn't make sense to have the side navigation drawer with a listview of the fast forward pause and rewind buttons.

I don't want to use a panel, because that opens up and eclipses the song entirely, whereas the buttons should only take up a 1/4 of the screen in order to retain a nonintrusive look.

If I were to make this function, are there any mods of navigation drawer or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use a custom view like the 
*AndroidSlidingUpPanel* provided by Umano: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

By calling both `setPanelHeight()` and `setSlidingEnabled()` you get a "permanent ~1/4 drawer" with your music controls.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding a library to my app, because I've heard that it makes the file size of the on market version quite burdernsome to the user. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: Well, it depends on the library you add, of course. In this case it's just a single class, plus `nineoldandroids` (which is quite small). It also needs the support library but you're probably including that one already. As a general rule, if a library does what you need, then you should include it. Much better than reinventing the wheel! :)

Comment: If I had +1, I'd give it to you. Unfortunately, I'm just a lowly peasant in the eyes of SO that doesn't have enough original questions to ask. Thanks :)